# How i can Add Metas like as Title, Description, Keywords in my laravel5.7 Website

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, meta, laravel-5.7

I want different title, description and keywords on each and every product page and category page in my laravel website.

How can I make my website seo friendly to do this?

I am using laravel 5.7.

Comment: What have you done yourself so far? (Add the appropriate meta tags with placeholders in your layout, fill the placeholders for every page you have)

Comment: I am using this...
<title>@hasSection ('title')@yield('title')
    @else Title Here @endif</title>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **default.blade.php** or master balde file you can create `yield()` and in blade file add `section()`

Example :
**app.blade.php**

```
 @yield('meta')
```

in View blade file **somefile.blade.php**

```
@section('meta')
    ....
    <meta property="title" content="Place your data here">
    <meta property="keywords" content="Place your data here">
    ....
@endsection
```

Comment: This is my code....

<title>@hasSection ('title')@yield('title')
    @else Title Here @endif</title>
    
how i can make it easier, because same title is calling on every page...

Comment: ?? @sumit. means

Comment: you tried this code ?

Comment: I tried your code, but i need to add foreach loop..and this is not working on website default page...do u have any idea how it will work with default page...

section('meta')
foreach($propertysingle as $addmetas)
    <meta property="title" content="{{$addmetas->property_title}}">
    <meta property="keywords" content="Place your data here">
endforeach
endsection

Comment: `@section('meta') 
@foreach($propertysingle as $addmetas) 
<meta property="title" content="{{$addmetas->property_title}}"> <meta property="keywords" content="Place your data here"> 
@endforeach 
@endsection`

Comment: update your question with your code

Comment: my question is this..if i am using `@yield('meta')` on my frontpage.blade.php (This page is replace by app.blade.php), then i am unable to find title,description, keywords on my website main page, but if i am using including this in internal page with something like this `@section('meta')
@foreach($propertysingle as $addmetas)
    <meta property="title" content="{{$addmetas->property_title}}">
    <meta property="description" content="{{$addmetas->meta_description}}">
    <meta property="keywords" content="{{$addmetas->blog_meta_tags}}">
@endforeach
@endsection`

Comment: then i can see title,description and keywords in my website, So now please let me know how i can see same thing on my website main index page.

Comment: your internal page (i assume internal pages are product display or other dynamic pages or blade ) extend `frontpage.blade.php` so you can use `@section('meta')` in internal page.And your home page is also extending `front.blade.php`. Suppose your home page is `index.blade.php`. you need to write meta in `index.blade.php` in `@section('meta')`.

Comment: I have done the same things as you describe here, but the main issue is this when i am using `@section('meta')    @endsection on internal pages, then i am getting 2 times title, description on internal pages. 1 title is coming from frontpage.blade.php (this file is using on every page @extends('layouts.frontpage')) file and another one is which i am adding on other blade file.

Comment: if you are setting meta in internal blade then why you are add meta in frontpage.blade.php

Comment: remove from `frontpage.blade.php`. use `section('meta')` in  all internal , dynamic and static page.